# Operator overloading for a set in c++

Tags: c++, set, overloading, operator-keyword

So I've created a new class called Tuples where Tuples takes in a vector of strings known as tupleVector. I then create a set of Tuples, meaning I need to overload the operators necessary to order elements and disallow duplicates.

Two questions:

1. which operator overload is necessary? Do I overload < or ==?
2. Assuming I must perform this overload within my Tuples class (so I can use the set of Tuples in other classes), is the following code correct?

   ```
   include "Tuples.h"
   Tuples::Tuples(vector<string> tuple){
       tupleVector = tuple;
   }
   vector<string> Tuples::getStrings()
   {
       return tupleVector;
   }
   bool Tuples::operator<(Tuples& other){
       return this->tupleVector<other.tupleVector;
   }
   bool Tuples::operator==(const Tuples& other)const{
       return this->tupleVector==other.tupleVector;
   }
   Tuples::~Tuples() {
       // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
   }
   ```

Comment: The `Tuples` name sounds like one `Tuples` instance represents a collection of tuples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to provide `operator<`. The container checks whether two items are equivalent by comparing them reflexively: they are equivalent if `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would like to use `std::sort` to sort a contiguous area in memory (array or standard container of the objects of `Tuples` type):

```
template< class RandomIt >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

You should overload `operator<` for your class `Tuples` or provide appropriate functor alternatively.

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order. The
>   order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved. The first
>   version uses operator< to compare the elements, the second version
>   uses the given comparison function object comp.

`operator==` is not needed, because it is easily emulated by standard sort algorithm with calls to `operator<` :

```
!( a < b) && !( b < a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends in which classes you like to use your own type. If you plan to use the class at many places you should overload the whole set of operators. But you can implement most other operators by calling a few own one:

```
bool operator==( const T &t ) const {
    // Implementation
}
```

To implement the `!=` operator, just call your `==` operator.

```
bool operator!=( const T &t ) const {
    return !operator==(t);
}
```

Similar you can easily implement the `<=`, `>`, `>=` operators by calling the `==` and `<` operator.